# Using canvas.getContext("2d") on multiple canvases on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm trying to make a page that allows users to choose which canvas size they want to draw on.

To do that I've created a page with 3 canvases of different sizes along with a button for each. I've hidden all the canvases in CSS then used jQuery to show a canvas when the relevant button is clicked. The problem is, that's broken the ability to actually draw on all canvases except the one that's first in my HTML doc. I suspect the problem is with this code:

HTML

```
<canvas width="400" height="250" class="small"></canvas>
<canvas width="600" height="400" class="medium"></canvas>
<canvas width="1000" height="800" class="large"></canvas>
```

JS

```
var context = $canvas[0].getContext("2d");

$canvas.mousedown(function(e){
  lastEvent = e;
  mouseDown = true;
}).mousemove(function(e){
   //Draw lines
  if(mouseDown) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(lastEvent.offsetX, lastEvent.offsetY);
    context.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
    context.strokeStyle = color;
    context.stroke();
    lastEvent = e;
  }
}).mouseup(function(){
  mouseDown = false;
}).mouseleave(function(){
  $canvas.mouseup(); 
});
```

Is there a way to select call 3 canvases with that .getContext string? [Full code in case it's useful](https://github.com/codedbyrob/Simple-Drawing-Application)

Comment: you want one context for multiple canvas?

Comment: You should only need a single canvas setting its size using the options. The drawings can be replicated by recording the points. By using 3x canvases you consume much more memory than needed, and drawing will be about 3x slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like that

```
var tab = [$canvas[0].getContext("2d"), $canvas[1].getContext("2d"), $canvas[2].getContext("2d")]
var lastEvent = null;
var mouseDown = false;

canvasParent.mousedown(function(e)
{
  lastEvent = e;
  mouseDown = true;
}).mousemove(function(e)
{
  if(mouseDown) {
    var i = 0;
    while (tab[i])
    {
      tab[i].beginPath();
      tab[i].moveTo(lastEvent.offsetX, lastEvent.offsetY);
      tab[i].lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
      tab[i].strokeStyle = color;
      tab[i].stroke();
      i += 1;
    }
      lastEvent = e;
  }
}).mouseup(function(e)
{
  mouseDown = false;
}).mouseleave(function()
{
  var i = 0;
  while (tab[i])
  {
    tab[i].mouseup()
    i += 1;
  }
});
```